# Issue with unix: merging two lines with sed

Tags: unix, sed, merge

I have a strange problem that can't get to fix. I am using the following bash script to merge two lines together on unix. However, the last column of the first line gets combined (with no space) with the first column of the second line. Can someone help please?

```
sed 'N;s/\n/  /' input.txt >> output.txt
```

input:

```
chr6    108930289   108930461   GWNJ-0842:521:GW1906282259th:8:1101:11373:39475:GCCAAGsize=1
HPV45   5328    5400    GWNJ-0842:521:GW1906282259th:8:1101:11373:39475:GCCAAGsize=1
chr3    153084969   153085002   GWNJ-0842:521:GW1906282259th:8:1101:14560:33322:GCCAATsize=6
HPV45   4014    4219    GWNJ-0842:521:GW1906282259th:8:1101:14560:33322:GCCAATsize=6
```

output: (HPV45 for example is attached to 1 before it)

```
chr6    108930289   108930461   GWNJ-0842:521:GW1906282259th:8:1101:11373:39475:GCCAAGsize=1HPV45   5328    5400    GWNJ-0842:521:GW1906282259th:8:1101:11373:39475:GCCAAGsize=1
chr3    153084969   153085002   GWNJ-0842:521:GW1906282259th:8:1101:14560:33322:GCCAATsize=6HPV45   4014    4219    GWNJ-0842:521:GW1906282259th:8:1101:14560:33322:GCCAATsize=6
```

Comment: Hi mevets, Thanks for your comment. It won't allow me to attach a txt file. I pasted a few of the lines from the input and output. Does that help?

Comment: Have you tried `sed 'N;s/\r\n/ /' file`?

Comment: Hi Oguz, Thanks for replying. I tried this and a couple of different options I found on the web. What happens with those is that the second line stays in the second line, only an space gets added before it. The only way I was able to actually merge the two lines was the code I used which ends up merging the texts together. If you can think of anything else, please let me know and I will try it.

Comment: What does `od -c ./input` show as far as what is between `size=1` and `HPV45`? For example, when I run it using your sample input I see `s   i   z   e   =   1  \n   H   P   V`

Comment: Hi Seige, Thanks. Yes it shows me the same thing as well for the input file. In the output file, however, it shows s i z e  =   1   H   P   V

Comment: That the output shows nothing between `size=1` and `HPV` just means that you have indeed removed the line that was in between, no?

Comment: As usual with line breaks, please make sure you have consistent line endings. Use `dos2linux` and retry.

Comment: Does the first line always start with `chr` and the second one with `HPV`?

Comment: with dos2linus, I get command not found.

Comment: yes, the first line always starts with ch and second with HPV.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification there. Don't use comments for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` as an alternative.

This script saves every odd numbered input line (starting with 1) and for every even numbered line it prints the saved line (without line separator) and the current one:

```
awk 'NR%2 {save=$0;}
!(NR%2) {print save,$0;}' input.txt >> output.txt
```

The next script relies on the patterns `chr` or `HPV` at the beginning of the line instead of using the line numbers:

```
awk '/^chr/ {save=$0;} 
/^HPV/ {print save,$0;}' input.txt >> output.txt
```

With the input from the question both scripts produce this output:

```
chr6    108930289   108930461   GWNJ-0842:521:GW1906282259th:8:1101:11373:39475:GCCAAGsize=1 HPV45   5328    5400    GWNJ-0842:521:GW1906282259th:8:1101:11373:39475:GCCAAGsize=1
chr3    153084969   153085002   GWNJ-0842:521:GW1906282259th:8:1101:14560:33322:GCCAATsize=6 HPV45   4014    4219    GWNJ-0842:521:GW1906282259th:8:1101:14560:33322:GCCAATsize=6
```

**Notes:**
The script based on line numbers will ignore the last line in case the total number of lines is odd.
The script based on patterns will produce wrong results if the input doesn't always contain pairs of matching lines.

Comment: Thanks! When I run this on the output file made from copying only the two lines I sent above, it doesn't work for me. I am using terminal on Mac to do this if it changes anything.

Comment: Could it be an issue with using delimiter on mac? The thing is the other ones awk code doesn't work for me either.

Comment: @neginValizadegan What exactly means "doesn't work for me"? As comments are not designed for this, please edit your question, show the input, the exact command you use and the resulting output. As others already wrote, you might have issues caused by wrong  or inconsistent line endings. Please also show the result of `od -c input.txt` and `od -c output.txt`. If your files are longer than a few lines, use something like `head -4 input.txt | od -c`

Comment: This one ended up working for me. Not why it didn't at first. Thanks!: awk 'NR%2 {save=$0;}
!(NR%2) {print save,$0;}' input.txt >> output.txt